# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs()

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna try to make test, member who logged in can create a job, this is my test code.

```
/** @test */
public function member_can_create_a_job(){
    $member = factory('App\Models\M_member')->create();
    $this->actingAs($member);

    $job = factory('App\Models\M_lowker')->make();
    $this->post('/lowker/tambah-lowker', $job->toArray())->assertRedirect('/lowker/tambah-lowker');
}
```

This is my App\Models\M_member

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class M_member extends Model{
    protected $table = "member";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ["nama", "email", "password", "alamat", "tgl_lahir", "remember_token"];

    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\M_lowker');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\M_komentar');
    }
}
```

When I run, I get error in cmd like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fUQl.png).

1) Tests\Feature\JPSTest::member_can_create_a_job TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\M_member given, called in I:\W 42 N\Home Work\Semester 5\Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak\Praktikum\jps\tests\Feature\JPSTest.php on line 35

I:\W 42 N\Home Work\Semester 5\Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak\Praktikum\jps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithAuthentication.php:16 I:\W 42 N\Home Work\Semester 5\Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak\Praktikum\jps\tests\Feature\JPSTest.php:35

ERRORS! Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Errors: 1.

Comment: Show the `App\Models\M_member` model

Comment: That's my M_member model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved with modify my M_member model like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class M_member extends Model implements Authenticatable{
    use AuthenticableTrait;
```

Answer (score 2):

This error tells you that the model which you are using is not extending the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract, which is necessary to use the actingAs method. If you have laravel's auth you can check the user model as an example of this . Which is something like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
```

So, try extending your model to have this functionality.

or you can implement the Authenticatable contract on your model like this

```
class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```

Comment: Now my model extends Model. Where I can place it?

Comment: I updated the answers, implementing the contract should work as well. Just make sure to add the classes of the contracts before your class

Comment: Error had change like this.

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\JPSTest::member_can_create_a_job
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/lowker/tambah-lowker'
+'http://localhost'

I:\W 42 N\Home Work\Semester 5\Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak\Praktikum\jps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:97
I:\W 42 N\Home Work\Semester 5\Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak\Praktikum\jps\tests\Feature\JPSTest.php:38

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 5, Failures: 1.

Comment: Apparently your test if failing because is not redirecting to the expected url. As you can see, you have place an assertRedirect to '/lowker/tambah-lowker' and instead your are been redirected to localhost, that is your home page. In the method to which you make that post call, which page should it return to ?

Comment: In the method to which I make that post call, I use return back(), it means redirect to '/lowker/tambah-lowker'

Comment: yes, you are making a post request to /lowker/tambah-lowker, that does not mean your are making it from that page. you could be in any page on your site and make that post request. Glad I could help, good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can add first() when you create user

```php
$user = factory('App\User')->create()->first();
```