# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

[image]

I have also tried some of the following methods, but none of them worked:

1. [Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::actingAs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203298/argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-foundation-testing-testcaseactingas)
2. [Problem with testing method with actingAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812723/problem-with-testing-method-with-actingas)

I hope there is another way I can solve this problem.

This is my ClipartTest.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ClipartTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_can_get_clipart()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $user = User::factory(3)->create();
        $this->actingAs($user, 'api');

        $this->getJson('/api/cliparts')
            ->assertStatus(201)
        ;
    }
```

This is my User.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Http\Traits\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Authenticatable, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    use Uuid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
```

This is my Clipart.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Http\Traits\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clipart extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Uuid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'image_id',
    ];
```

Comment: It is really important that you **READ** the errors... it clearly says `instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, so you are getting a `Collection` instead of a `Model`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating 3 users with the factory and therefore the `$user` will actually return a collection of 3 users.

Instead of `User::factory(3)->create()` do `User::factory()->create()` so that it would return a single user model.

Comment: Initially I also wrote the same as above but then it still got the same error message as I shared.
I tried luckily creating 3 users with the factory and as a result it still doesn't work

Comment: It should be just one user. Also, what are you using for the API? Laravel Passport?

Comment: I found out it looks like I'm not using laravel passport. Is it the cause of the above error???